# Hide status bar value from href url when mouse hover a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

This is the link that I have:

```
href='" . $ajax_like_link . "' data-task='like' data-post_id='" . $post_id . "' data-nonce='" . $nonce . "'>";
```

And I want to replace the displayed link value from status and set to `javascript:void(0)`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML - overRide statusbar link location display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573942/html-override-statusbar-link-location-display)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='" . $ajax_like_link . "'">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! it work like a charm! = href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='location.href='" . $ajax_like_link . "' data-task='like' data-post_id='" . $post_id . "' data-nonce='" . $nonce . "''>";

Comment: What about target="_blank" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by calling javascript function instead of link in href:

```
   <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='gotoLink(\"". $ajax_like_link ."\")' .......>link</a>
    <script>
    function gotoLink(url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the status with `window.status=''` but  most browsers will block attempts to change the status line by default for security reasons

```
<a href="link" onmouseover="window.status='javascript:void(0)';" onmouseout="window.status='';">link here</a>
```

So a better way is to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='" . $ajax_like_link . "'">Link</a>
```

Comment: <a href="link" onmouseover="window.status='javascript:void(0)';" onmouseout="window.status='';">link here</a> *NOT WORK*

Answer (score 0):

a more shorter syntax of doing this is

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='" . $ajax_like_link . "'">Link</a>
```

and there are many other ways of doing this, you can create a jquery function and just put the url in the attibute. e.g

```
<a href="javascript:;" rel='" . $ajax_like_link . "'" class="goto">Link</a>

$(".goto").click(function() {
    var gotolink = $(this).attr('rel')
    if(gotolink!=undefined || gotolink!='')
         location.href = gotolink;
});
```