# Hide urls being shown at the bottom of the page, when hovered over anchor tags

Tags: css

Using CSS, is it possible to hide url/href at the bottom of the page, when hovered over anchor tags?

Comment: This is a browser feature, not a HTML/CSS feature. You probably can't hide it without changing the `href` attribute. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677188/html-javascript-hiding-link-destination-and-opening-link-in-new-tab )

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done using only CSS. Using javascript you might be able to manipulate it, but that most likely would lead to crawlers not detecting your links on your html or form problems regarding accessibility.