# Remove showing hyperlink in status bar on hyperlink/button on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, statusbar

In my application navigator status bar is displayed by default at the bottom of each screen and URLs linked to buttons and icons will be displayed on it.

**Like this:**
[image: URL on Status bar]

I do not want to show URL associated to hyperlink or button at bottom of the web page using JavaScript.

*What I have tried so far:*

*Setting window.status = '' onmouseover property of hyperlink/button, but this is not working.*

Browser I'm using are `Internet Explore IE11` and `Firefox 38.8.0`.

Comment: nope your not using  Internet Explore IE11 and Firefox 38.8.0 your using a server with a database and a script, what have you tried?

Comment: remove the link do a form submit with the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide status bar value from href url when mouse hover a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814076/hide-status-bar-value-from-href-url-when-mouse-hover-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

It's working for me.

I have tested this on both browsers: Internet Explore and Firefox

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='http://yourlink.com/'">click here</a>
```

Comment: @geeky_ninja if it is working for you then accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to show URL associated to hyperlink or button at bottom of the web page [using JavaScript]

Statusbar shows the `href`.

So: *don't* specify an href.

There's no need for javascript to "hide" it.

Given that it's a link you probably want to be able to click it, so add a click handler with jquery and you can style with css to make it look like a link.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#saveLink").click(function() {
    location.href = $(this).data("href");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='saveLink' title='Click to save' data-href='http://google.com'>no status bar link on hover</a>
<br/>
<a href='http://google.com'>link shown in status bar on hover</a>
```

If you need keyboard support (tab) then you'll need an href, so can just go with `href='#'`

Comment: "title" displays a tooltip; the author asks about the statusbar :)

Comment: @kolypto If I recall, I was leading with it as an intro - but I agree, doesn't make much sense.